# ExtJS "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'added' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I'm writing a module to the application (Group Office) and I have a problem with extjs. I created a main panel with TabPanel and when I run it I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'added' of undefined
```

If anyone knows what might be causing this without code review? I am using extjs 3.4.0.

Comment: Please provide some of your front-end code for us to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23534201/1448983
Even though there is no answer, the upvoted comment could provide some help.